# Return when a higher role is mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
let arole = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

How can make the code to return if the mentioned role is higher than the message author's highest role?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: show some code and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<Role>.comparePositions(role1, role2)` method. Here is an example:

```js
const { Role } = require("discord.js");

const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
const highest = message.member.roles.highest;
if (Role.comparePositions(highest, role) <= 0)
    console.log("Mentioned role's position is equal or higher than author's role");
```